# What is "הער״ט איר ניט"?

Tags: translation, transliteration

[נטעי גבריאל, in הלכות נשואין, volume 2, chapter 118, section 8, footnote 11](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46546&pgnum=296), cites [the מהרי״ל‬](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=33228&pgnum=17) ([biographical information](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yaakov_ben_Moshe_Levi_Moelin)):

> שכשהיה קורא לאשתו אמר בלשון‬ ‫אשכנז הער״ט איר ניט כדרך העולם שהזיווגים אין מזכירין שמותיהן‬ ‫כשקורין זה את זו או זו את זה‬

Or, in my own translation:

> When he would call his wife, he'd say in German<sup>[1]</sup> "הער״ט איר ניט", in accordance with the way the world acts, that couples calling one another don't mention one another's names.

Any idea what German<sup>[1]</sup> words are being transliterated as "הער״ט איר ניט", or what they mean?

---

<sup>[1]</sup> actually some dialect of what we now call [Early New High German](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_German), I suppose

Comment: I wonder if this was always his practice, or just when other people were around. And I'm not sure what's unique about the practice if "the world" indeed acted that way; what phrase did everyone else use?

Comment: stumbled across this while searching, might shed light on the whole concept (I only read the first page): http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=42519&pgnum=485

Answer (score 5, accepted):

הער״ט איר ניט = Did you not hear.

I have heard some Chasidim who call their wife Her-nor הער-נאר = Listen

Comment: Note that the pronoun "איר" (versus the more commonplace "דו") denotes a level of honor and respect.

Comment: do you know what that phrase is supposed to convey?

Comment: @Menachem - Something like "Yo!" in modern parlance (though obviously a lot more refined).

Comment: @Dave, re "...denotes a level...": was that true in the _Maharil_'s days, too?

Comment: @msh210 I would assume so.

Comment: @msh210 - If I'm not mistaken, "ihr" is the plural form of "du," so when used in the 2nd person it inherently carries an sense of respect.

Comment: [Hear ye not](https://translate.google.com/#auto/en/%D7%94%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%98%20%D7%90%D7%99%D7%A8%20%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%98)